# Does 'he is not a swimmer' mean 'he cannot swim,' or 'he doesn't swim regularly'?

Tags: meaning

Does ***he is not a swimmer*** mean ***he cannot swim***, or ***he doesn't swim regularly***? Or, both, ***he cannot and doesn't swim***?

In the following passage, does 'Bill Boomer ***had not swum***' or 'Bill Boomer ***couldn't swim***'?

> One memorable day, Bill Boomer addressed a coaches’ clinic I happened
> to be attending. Speaker after speaker had gone on and on about how
> they trained their swimmers by “building the engine and fuel tank,” so
> to speak — throwing enough hard work at them that their bodies had no
> choice but to build endurance. Then Boomer took the podium and dropped
> his bomb. He posed an obvious question, but one I’d never heard in two
> decades of attending such meetings: “How can we teach people to swim,
> at any given speed, with less effort?” His answer was just as
> disarming: “By reshaping the vessel.” After all, swimmers had a lot in
> common with boats, and like a naval architect Boomer knew there were
> ways to improve the efficiency of their “hull designs.” Apparently he
> had the advantage of fresh eyes, since ***he hadn’t even been a
> swimmer himself***, studying movement science in school and coaching
> soccer and track. So Boomer came to swimming minus the usual baggage
> of how things “ought” to be done and with a deep understanding of the
> way the human body moves. That enabled him to see things the rest of
> us had missed.

[Total Immersion: The Revolutionary Way To Swim Better, Faster, and Easier](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=I5kleqTzqyEC&pg=PT17&lpg=PT17&dq=%E2%80%9CBy%20reshaping%20the%20vessel.%E2%80%9D%20After%20all,%20swimmers%20had%20a%20lot%20in%20common%20with%20boats,%20and%20like%20a%20naval%20architect%20Boomer%20knew%20there%20were%20ways%20to%20improve%20the%20efficiency%20of%20their%20%E2%80%9Chull%20designs.%E2%80%9D%20Apparently%20he%20had%20the%20advantage%20of%20fresh%20eyes,%20since%20he%20hadn%E2%80%99t%20even%20been%20a%20swimmer%20himself,%20studying%20movement%20science%20in%20school%20and%20coaching%20soccer%20and%20track.&source=bl&ots=hDZL2b6nG9&sig=ACfU3U2QGLLxA5_OGJvezBfPQCWK0kw9jQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZ08q9_qvvAhWLc3AKHfYvDtMQ6AEwAHoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9CBy%20reshaping%20the%20vessel.%E2%80%9D%20After%20all%2C%20swimmers%20had%20a%20lot%20in%20common%20with%20boats%2C%20and%20like%20a%20naval%20architect%20Boomer%20knew%20there%20were%20ways%20to%20improve%20the%20efficiency%20of%20their%20%E2%80%9Chull%20designs.%E2%80%9D%20Apparently%20he%20had%20the%20advantage%20of%20fresh%20eyes%2C%20since%20he%20hadn%E2%80%99t%20even%20been%20a%20swimmer%20himself%2C%20studying%20movement%20science%20in%20school%20and%20coaching%20soccer%20and%20track.&f=false)

Comment: It means whatever the speaker intended at the time. To know what such statements are supposed to mean, you first have to know the context.

Comment: In this case, it probably means he wasn't a regular (and particularly, not a competitive) swimmer.

Answer (score 1):

"He hadn't even been a swimmer" could mean either one, really, as Ronald Sole points out. Perhaps he knows how to swim well enough not to drown, or perhaps he doesn't even know that. The point is that, even though he was not a *professional* or *competitive* swimmer, his education and experience in the field of movement science allowed him to develop a method to coach swimming better than other peoples' methods. In fact the passage says that his method was better *because* he had no experience with swimming and was able to look at things without any preconceived ideas about how it "should" be done.

If instead the sentence read "He hadn't **ever** been a swimmer" that would more strongly indicate that he doesn't even know how to swim, but even then it could mean "He hadn't ever been a competitive swimmer."